# What language is Haskell written in?

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, io

Also (besides the title question), is there source code available for different impure Haskell functions like IO?

I don't mean the Haskell side of the code, but whatever Haskell implements to do IO.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Haskell [implementations](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Implementations) are written in a range of languages.

For example, [GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) is:

- runtime:   a mixture of C, assembly and C--
- compiler:  Haskell, Happy (for parsing), and Alex (for lexing)
- libraries: Haskell and a few C bindings, a little assembly and C--

The [primops](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/prelude/primops.txt.pp) are the native instructions of the runtime. They in turn are implemented [in the runtime](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/master/rts/PrimOps.cmm) via [C, C-- and assembly](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/master/includes/Stg.h) fragments.

IO in particular is mediated via the IO manager, and via [foreign libraries of IO primitives.](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/include/HsBase.h)